# “J'habite Lille” or “j'habite à Lille”?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, verbes, indications-de-lieu

I've often seen phrases like “*j'habite Lille*”, “*j'habite un appartement*” instead of “*j'habite à Lille*”, “*j'habite dans un appartement*”. Is it correct to remove the prepositions?

Answer (score 10):

You can say both, as *habiter* [is both transitive and intransitive.](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/habiter#Verbe.C2.A01)  However, in everyday conversation, the intransitive form is more common.

Answer (score 3):

Les deux se parlent, mais seul *habiter à* doit être retenu pour l'écrit.

On peut habiter :

> - *chez* quelqu'un,
> - *près d*'une autre ville,
> - *en* ville (celle dont on vient de parler), synonyme de "intra-muros" (entre les murs [de la citadelle] en latin)
> - *à* l'hôtel

---

Familièrement on supprime le *à* mais on ajoute aussi le *sur* pour indiquer que l'on habite près de la localité citée :

J'habite *sur* PARIS, pour dire que l'on est francilien (habitant de l'Île de France, une des vingt-deux région de l'hexagone) mais pas parisien (habitant intra-muros).

Ce sont là deux expressions (sans *à* et *sur*) que l'on peut connaître mais qu'il vaut mieux ne pas utiliser, surtout lorsque l'on essaie de parler correctement le français.

Comment: "J'habite sur PARIS, pour dire que l'on est francilien mais pas parisien" - ah, moi j'interprète au contraire cette expression comme pouvant très bien être Paris intra muros ou la petite couronne.

Comment: @guillaume31 En effet, l'emploie de *sur* évolue rapidement et devient moins clivant. Toutefois les habitants des communes de la proche périphérie de PARIS (ou dont les noms sont rarement cités) se domicilient familièrement *sur* Paris lorsqu'ils savent que leur interlocuteur n'est pas un fin connaisseur de l'Île de France

Comment: @cl-r: J'ai beau faire allusion à http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2353912, pourriez-vous expliciter votre acception de **clivant** ?

Comment: @LePressentiment *cliver* : Fendre (un corps minéral, un diamant) dans le sens naturel de ses couches lamellaires -- *clivage* (acception 2, depuis 1932) Séparation par plan, par niveau : "un nouveau clivage social prenait vie sous son regard." [Gracq] (extrait du petit Robert) -- J'aurais du écrire *le clivage devient moins perceptible*, mais, comme le lien l'indique, *clivant* entre dans les habitudes.

Comment: *Les deux se **parlent*** ??

Comment: @jlliagre — Utilisation d’une tournure familière, comme "le français se parle" ou s’écrit [https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=le+fran%C3%A7ais+se+parle&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cle%20fran%C3%A7ais%20se%20parle%3B%2Cc0 ] … l’oblitération d’un possible dialogue est induite lorsqu’il y a deux sujets

Comment: J'ai du mal à appréhender *se parler* avec un autre sujet que des personnes ou des langues. Pas de problème avec *les voisins se parlent* (pronominal réfléchi) ou *les langues germaniques se parlent...* (pronominal passif) mais *les deux phrases se parlent* ou *les deux expressions se parlent* me laissent perplexe. J'aurais écrit *Les deux expressions se disent*.  En revanche, pas de problème avec *les deux expressions **me** parlent* (m'inspirent quelque chose).

Comment: @jlliagre — Le modèle :  « Le français se parle bien ou ne se parle pas. » Je reconnais que j’ai souvent entendu la tournure évoquée entre Loire et Gironde. Certes *se disent* est plus usuel. Les langues que vous évoquez sont composées de phrases et de mots qui se parlent, se chantent, se murmurent… ou se lisent. La phrase *Les deux se murmurent* vous interpelle-t-elle autant ?

Comment: Aucun problème avec *les deux se murmurent*. On peut bien murmurer un mot ou une phrase, les chanter ou les lire, mais *parler une phrase, parler un mot*, en dehors de l'expression *ne pas parler un mot de <langue>*, je ne connaissais pas. Je serais curieux de trouver des références de cet usage.

Comment: @jlliagre — L’équivalent sous une forme régionale, *ça se parle* :  https://books.google.fr/books?id=7QQViRtPWIUC&pg=PA104&dq=%22%C3%A7a+se+parle%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwioxpW_v7HjAhXyDmMBHYBSAdgQ6AEIMDAB#v=onepage&q=%22%C3%A7a%20se%20parle%22&f=false

Comment: Ah oui. Entre Loire et Gironde, mais bien au large ;-) (Québec)

Comment: Dont Beaucoup sont partis de Saintonge !

Answer (score 1):

In spoken French, I hear the prepositionless form most often used when followed with something else, to make a sentence shorter and more fluid.

> J'habite à Paris depuis cinq ans, et [...].

could beneficially be replaced by

> J'habite Paris depuis cinq ans, et [...].

Similarly,

> Elle habite dans un grand appartement de 120 m² depuis 1978.
>
> => Elle habite un grand appartement de 120 m² depuis 1978.

However, with nothing after :

I'd rather say

> Je m'appelle Guillaume, j'habite à Paris.
>
> *(sounds complete, round)*

than

> Je m'appelle Guillaume, j'habite Paris.
>
> *(...OK so what ? Kind of falls flat, sounds a bit
>   dry, leaves us expecting something else)*

This might be a matter of everyone's own ear, but I do see a pattern in there.