# Habiter (dans) cette maison

Tags: usage, prépositions

> Il y a quatre ans que j'habite dans cette maison.
>
> Il y a quatre ans que j'habite cette maison.

Y a-t-il des différences entre les deux phrases ? Laquelle est la plus correcte et laquelle la plus courante ?

Comment: Question similaire: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7589/jhabite-lille-or-jhabite-%c3%a0-lille

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selon le TLFi, [habiter](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/habiter) s'emploie aussi bien en forme transitive qu'intransitive bien que la version 8 du dictionnaire de l'Académie (1932 si je ne me trompe pas) ne reconnait que la forme transitive.

On peut donc utiliser les deux formulations, néanmoins une analyse [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=habiter%20une%20maison%2Chabiter%20dans%20une%20maison&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chabiter%20une%20maison%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chabiter%20dans%20une%20maison%3B%2Cc0) donne une nette préférence pour la forme transitive *« habiter une maison »*.

Answer (score 1):

Je dirais que les deux sont correctes mais qu'en langage courant la deuxième phrase est plus utilisée que la première. Je n'ai pas d'explication pour ça par contre