# When do I need to use a preposition with habiter?

Tags: grammaire

I am seeing some contradictions in my research as I learn the French language. I am trying to conclude when to include a preposition or not in my speech. For example, in which of the following, if any, are prepositions optional?

- J'habite (à) Paris.
- J'habite (dans) une maison.
- J'habite au Canada.
- J'habite aux États-Unis.
- J'habite en France.

My understanding that a preposition is only required for countries and continents.

This site seems to suggest it is always necessary: https://frenchtogether.com/vocabulary/jhabite/

While this one allows it to be optional: https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/habiter-vs-vivre/

Is this a question between what is right and what is common?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can go by the answer to this question [*J'habite Lille* or *j'habite à Lille*](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/7589/358) saying that *habiter* is both transitive and intransitive, although it doesn't give examples with a country name, so I'm adding it here. Both can be said, *j'habite la France* and *j'habite en France*.
Here's a sentence from *Le Petit Prince* by Saint-Exupéry:

> cette grande personne habite la France où elle a faim et froid.

An ngram shows that the intransitive form is more common nowadays which supports my own impression of spoken French.
[image]

The same seems to work for continents:

> Leur fille, adulte, mariée, habite les États-Unis. (from an [academic paper](https://books.openedition.org/psorbonne/978?lang=en) by André Kaspi and Catherine Le Dret)

The only case I would not use the preposition in front of the country name is when *habiter* means  "populate", as in:

> [Les premiers peuples qui ont habité le Canada étaient des nomades,](https://archive.org/stream/letintamarre19962013/letintamarre19962013_djvu.txt)

Comment: This is an incredible insight, thanks very much!

Comment: « Cette grande personne habite *la* France où… », *la* pour une tierce personne, mais si je dis « j'habite *la* France… » c'est que cela ne fait pas longtemps, les natifs disent plutôt « J'habite *en* France » quand on parle de soi ou de proches, le *en* me semble plus soutenu — Parfois les gens du voyage disent « Je parle *la* France », ce qui met hors jeu le *la* quand on parle de soi :-)